# How to optimize my stored procedure so that it runs quicker

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

i have the following storedprocedure that when i run it,it takes over an hour to process for a 3 day week range, and it doesnt even come back with alot of data, so i am not sure why its taking this long to run.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Verification]
    @BranchID VARCHAR(MAX),
    @StartDate DATETIME, 
    @EndDate DATETIME,
    @UserName VARCHAR(150),
    @Password VARCHAR(50) 
    --WITH ENCRYPTION 
AS
BEGIN

    EXEC Security.rpt_HasAccess @UserName, @Password    

    SELECT
         SB.Name as Branch
        ,FVD.TrackDateTime AS [Date] 
        ,ISNULL(' ' + FA.Number + ' -',  '') + ' ' + FA.FirstName + ' ' + FA.LastName AS USER
        ,FV.FirstName + ' ' + FV.LastName AS Client
        ,SU.UserName 
        ,FGLT.Name 
        ,REPLACE(br.BreadCrumb, '||', ' - ') + ' - ' + GM.Name + ' - ' + p.Name + ISNULL(' ' + gmo.NameSuffix, '') + ISNULL(' ' + p1.Name, '')  AS BC
        ,FGL.[Entry] 
        ,CASE WHEN FV.Number IS NOT NULL THEN FV.Number ELSE FV.Pass END AS PassorNot
        ,FV.Address 
        ,FV.PhoneNumber   
    FROM Verification FV
        JOIN Detail FVD  ON FVD.VerificationID = FV.VerificationId
        LEFT JOIN GeneralLedger FGL  ON (FGL.TicketID = FVD.TicketID AND FGL.TypeCode = FVD.TypeCode) OR (FGL.LedgerID = FVD.LedgerID)
        LEFT JOIN LedgerType FGLT  ON FGLT.LedgerTypeCode = FGL.LedgerTypeCode
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Account FA  ON FA.AccountID = FGL.AccountID
        LEFT JOIN [security].SysUser SU  ON SU.UserID = FVD.UserID
        LEFT JOIN Ticket BT  ON BT.TicketID = FVD.TicketID 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT MarketOptionID, TicketID FROM TicketDetail  WHERE Current = 1) AS BTD ON BTD.TicketID = BT.TicketID 
        LEFT JOIN MarketOption GMO  ON GMO.MarketOptionID = BTD.MarketOptionID 
        LEFT JOIN Market GM  ON GM.MarketID = GMO.MarketID
        LEFT JOIN Participant p  ON GMO.ParticipantID = p.ParticipantID 
        LEFT JOIN Participant AS p1  ON GMO.ParticipantID1 = p1.ParticipantID and GMO.ParticipantID1 IS NOT NULL 
        LEFT JOIN [system].[Branch] SB  ON FGL.BranchID = SB.BranchID 
        LEFT JOIN Crumb br  ON gm.GID = br.GID
    WHERE FVD.TrackDateTime > @StartDate 
        AND     FVD.TrackDateTime  < @EndDate + 1 
        AND     SB.BranchID IN (SELECT CAST(Data AS INT) FROM [system].[Split](@BranchID, ','))
    ORDER BY SB.Name, FVD.TrackDateTime

END
```

is there a better way that i can make the above query structure run faster? its looking through alot of tables which i need.

Comment: just so you know, left join and left outer join are the same thing

Comment: @Anonymous didnt notice i did that,thanks

Comment: Do you have indexes on the tables you are joining?

Comment: You can use Loop,Hash and Merge Join conditionally, Google them...

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/option-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Why is this a subquery: `LEFT JOIN (SELECT MarketOptionID, TicketID FROM TicketDetail  WHERE Current = 1) AS BTD ON BTD.TicketID = BT.TicketID` ? Why not just `LEFT JOIN TicketDetail  BTD ON BTD.TicketID = BT.TicketID AND BTD.Current = 1`?

Comment: `SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY (OBJECT_ID(N'[system].[Split]'),'IsDeterministic')` -?

Comment: `< @EndDate + 1` is potentially incorrect since time is still there. Can be fixed by `set @EndDate = DATEADD(DD, CAST(@EndData as DATE), 1)` in the beginning of sp. Or change param type to `date`.

Comment: @IvanStarostin thanks for that, i was going through the query again and i realized at the point on the join where there is an OR condition thats the point that takes extremely long,if i have to remove it it runs with in a second. do you know off another method that i could use instead of the OR condition

Comment: When talking about performance and seeing a splitter in the code you need to post that splitter function. So many splitters are horrific for performance because they have loops. Post your splitter?

Answer (score -2):

**First** thing you have to do is:

`Use index <Specific fields> to each and every table.`

**Second:**

I've been noticed that you are getting all fields from your table which is not a good idea instead of getting the specific fields that you wanted to view something like:

You are using a bunch of this way:

`LEFT JOIN GeneralLedger`

It means you are collecting all fields (It means `Select *`) from that particular table instead of picking the specific fields like:

`LEFT JOIN
SELECT (FIELD1,FIELD2) FROM YOURTABLE`

Just pick only the fields you wanted and avoid `select *`

**Third:**

If you have a lot of user's fetching data to that particular DB table.

**Fourth:**

Just consider that looking forward the more you adding data to your DB the more you spend some time in fetching.(`10 or 20 years more from the date you started for example. How's your query performance?`). This is the question that we might think.

Comment: "Second" is nonsense. The rest of the answer has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStarostin.. I am waking him up the real situation when it comes of fetching data from db. We all don't know what kind of structure he has.

Comment: The "second" issue is what you spend most of your time talking about and it is complete rubbish.